# Why does Hibernate only Auto-Flush inside a transaction?

Tags: hibernate, transactions, flush

What is the rationale behind this behavior?

If for some reason I execute two suitable operations outside a transaction (not recommended, I know!) and I've configured Hibernate to auto-flush, I would *expect* it to auto-flush if the second operation is one that should trigger an auto-flush (like `list`, `iterate`, or `executeUpdate`).

That's exactly what would happen, if not for the explicit check on the second line of the `autoFlushIfRequried` method:

```
protected boolean autoFlushIfRequired(Set querySpaces) throws HibernateException {
    errorIfClosed();
    if ( ! isTransactionInProgress() ) {
        // do not auto-flush while outside a transaction
        return false;
    }
    AutoFlushEvent event = new AutoFlushEvent(querySpaces, this);
    AutoFlushEventListener[] autoFlushEventListener = listeners.getAutoFlushEventListeners();
    for ( int i = 0; i < autoFlushEventListener.length; i++ ) {
    autoFlushEventListener[i].onAutoFlush(event);
    }
    return event.isFlushRequired();
}
```

---

**Update**: Thank you [axtavt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103154/axtavt) for finding the Hibernate issue that prompted this change (in 3.2): [FlushMode.AUTO -> COMMIT when outside a transaction](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1410).

A related issue is still open: [delay IDENTITY insertions in the case of FlushMode.MANUAL/NEVER](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2439), but neither discussion provides the rationale for saying "When operating outside a transaction, FlushMode.AUTO is a bad thing."

Comment: _When_ do you expect it to autoflush?

Comment: @axtavt - I've updated my question to be a bit more specific. I expect it to auto-flush if I perform an operation that normally auto-flushes, like `list`, `iterate`, or `executeUpdate`. I don't understand the relevance of transactions to the code above.

Comment: I've seen and upvoted. Hibernate guys say that "it's a bad thing": http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1410

Answer (score 3):

Because the docummentation for `FlushMode` says

> The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state. This is the default flush mode.

So, auto doesn't mean what you think it means. The name is, arguably, badly chosen, but it doesn't mean a flush is made after each session operation. It's thus not similar to JDBC's autocommit, which makes a commit after ever JDBC statement.